# Powershell Add-Type - Add member of type dictionary/hashtable

Tags: class, powershell, dictionary, hashtable, add-type

I am trying to add a custom type in powershell like this:

```
Add-Type @'
public class MyType {
    public string name;
    public string type;
    public hashtable data;
    public string category;
}
'@
```

However, the type hashtable, dictionary does not exist. I have looked around for examples regarding this but could not find any.

Might add, that I do not want to use Add-Member.

Any ideas?

/Patrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things:

1. Capitalize "[Hashtable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx)", C# is case-sensitive
2. Add a `using` statement, so the compiler can resolve the full type name

---

```
Add-Type @'
using System.Collections;

public class MyType {
    public string name;
    public string type;
    public Hashtable data;
    public string category;
}
'@
```